# How to get data from excel tables with different headers on different rows?

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to get data from an excel workbook with 3 different tables having headers on 3 different rows.

Before you ask me, I cannot modify the excel file as it is is password protected and can only read from it.

The 3 tables contains the same data type (such as groupname, members, description etc.) that will then be used for other loops.

The headers of the 3 tables are almost identical except for the first column where a different title is being used. Something similar to this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Header1       |      Members     |    Description   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        Group1       |   User1, User2   |    group desc    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        Group2       |   User3, User4   |    group desc    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|


|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Header2       |      Members     |    Description   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        Group3       |   User1, User3   |    group desc    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        Group4       |   User2, User4   |    group desc    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I actually don't care about the headers names being preserved, I just need to grab the data within the tables to store in variables and use in foreach loops at later stage.

What is the best approach I could go with?

I have tried importing the single header cells with different names and then the common ones, but then I'm stuck.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{ 
InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('C:\Temp') }

$null = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

$Groups1 = Import-Excel -Path $FileBrowser.FileName -WorksheetName 
"Workbook1" -StartRow "16" -EndRow "22" -HeaderName "Header1"

$Groups2 = Import-Excel -Path $FileBrowser.FileName -WorksheetName 
"Workbook1" -StartRow "24" -EndRow "30" -HeaderName "Header2"

$Other = Import-Excel -Path $FileBrowser.FileName -WorksheetName 
"Workbook1" -StartRow "16" -EndRow "38"-StartColumn "2" -EndColumn "5" 
-HeaderName "Members", "Description"
```

I would like to have organised data that could be used in loops for AD groups creation.

Comment: can you export the worksheet as a text file? if so, you can parse the sections individually ... [*grin*]

Comment: would be easier? i thought that using import-excel and some array/hashtable could do the trick and i feel i'm really close to a solution but i don't know what is the next step

Comment: my understanding is that ImportExcel will try to give you a collection of objects. can it grab a SECTION of a worksheet for that? if so, then use it. if not, then **_for me_** if would be easier to grab the raw text, break it into sections, strip away any unwanted stuff, and feed it to `ConvertFrom-CSV` to get three independent collections of objects.